# How to disable copy and paste outside of the Amazon EC2 remote desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a Windows Server 2016 instance on an Amazon EC2. Is there a way to disable copy and paste (files and clipboard) outside of the remote desktop? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Local Group ploicy Editor ( search in windows search bar )

under Local Computer Policy --> User Configuration -->

Administrative Templates --> Windows Components -->

Remote Desktop Service --> Remote Desktop Session Host -->

Device and Resource Redirection --> in right window select 
    "Do not allow Clipboard redirection rule and enable it.

So user will not allowed to copy/paste files from RDP session.

Comment: Can we apply this to a particular local user account? I have a EC2 instance with 3 accounts(Admin, 2 local accounts). I want to disable copy/paste from/to RDP from local computer for a particular local user account of EC2 instance. Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks